# Eclipse CDT Build Configurations - Build All at once

Tags: eclipse, configuration, build, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT, I have several build configurations. I want to build them all at once. They can be built in parallel or in serial, it doesnt matter, there are no dependancies. What I am looking for is a one-click build which will recompile all the build configurations with one action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Preferences Dialog (in "Window" menu on Windows, and on "Eclipse" on OS X), in the subtree `C/C++` → `Build`, there is an option to select "Build All Configurations in Each Project"

See the screenshot:

[image: Screen shot of Build Configuration Options to build all at once in Eclipse]

Comment: Is it possible to do this only for a specific project?